# Wordpress custom iframe short code fails to return the iframe

Tags: php, wordpress

basically i want to create a shortcode to add iframes into apost/page etc. 
I've tried the following, but for some reason the frame appears blank .

```
//custom added functions
add_shortcode('wrap', 'addWrapper'); 
function addWrapper($atts,$content=null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "src" => 'http://google.com',
        "height" => '300',
        "width" => '400',
        "scrolling" => 'auto'
    ), $atts));

    return '<div id="iwrapper">
        <iframe src="'.$src.'" height="'.$height.'"  width="'.$width.'" scrolling="'.$scrolling.'"></iframe>
        </div>';
```

if i try to return anything else , for example a simple HELLO WORLD text, it returns just fine. Why is it that wordpress blanks out the iframe ?  i tried to manually send an iframe too , but nothing (`<iframe width="150" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com" frameborder="0" type="text/html"></iframe>` )..

when i use firebug to debbug i do not see any errors :S

```
 <div id="iwrapper">
<iframe src="http://google.com" height="300" width="400" scrolling="auto"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has some security restrictions that will remove iframes. It's hard to see however with the example above how you are loading in the iframe.  Are you building a wordpress plugin?

Comment: actually, i just opened the functions.php( of one of the standard themes, like twenty eleven theme), and typed it in. I thought to try to make it work first, and later try to build a plugin out of it

Comment: i've downloaded a few other iframe plugins to see how they worked , but most of them just returned the iframe code like i am doing. isnt there a way to bypass theese security restrictions?

Comment: Also if instead of a webpage, i add a video element as the source, it displays just fine . for example if i put src= http://www.youtube.com/embed/iHJoMPBgkV0 , it is displayed., but if i put eg: www.google.com as the source, it is not :S